# My Excel 2007 macro - what does Argument not optional mean?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: what is wrong with my macro?]

Please advise me what is wrong with my Excel 2007 macro
thank you very much

Comment: Learn how to ask any question http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Can you revise this so the readable text of your question actually _exceeds_ the markup used to display the image? How would _anyone_ find this question by searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a parameter is supposed to be sent to a function by its definition but it is not sent, this error occurs.
Please note that you *can* assign optional paramters like this:

```vb
Function Something(ByVal text as String, Optional number as Long = 26)
```

By placing the **Optional** keyword, the function can still be called even without that paramater being passed in to it. The = xxx is where you put the default value in the case that it is not provided.

If you decide not to declare the type of the Optional paramter (making it a Variant), you can use the ultra convenient **IsMissing()** function to see if it was passed in or not.

Answer (score 2):

The function needs one or more parameters (argument) which you didn't provide. And since that argument is not optional, meaning you *have* to provide it, Excel can't execute your macro.

Comment: You can find full details of the InchesToPoints function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209927(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a number into the second call to inchesToPoints()

Comment: thanks for your reply. please advise How I can fix. I dont know VBA

Answer (score 0):

Seems like function `.InchesToPoints()` needs argument to be passed. 
Like you have passed value 0.36 in your first call of `.InchesToPoints()` for variable `.LeftMargin`

Pass the proper argument for function called for variable `.RightMargin`